# using 64 bits integers in 64 bits compilers and OSes

Tags: c++, optimization, 64-bit

I have a doubt about when to use 64 bits integers when targeting 64 bits OSes.

Has anyone done conclusive studies focused on the speed of the generated code?

- It is better to use 64 bits integers as params for funcs or methods? (Ex: uint64 myFunc(uint64 myVar))
  If we use 64 bits integers as params it takes more memory but maybe it will be more efficient.
  What about if we know that some value should be always less than, for example, 10. We still continue using 64 bit integers for this param?
- It is better to use 64 bits integers as return types?
  Is there some penalty for using 32-bit as return value?
- It is better to use 64 bits integers for loops? (for(size_t i=0; i<...)) In this case, I suppose it.
  Is there some penalty for using 32-bit variables for loops?
- It is better to use 64 bits integers as indexes for pointers? (Ex: myMemory[index]) In this case, I suppose it.
  Is there some penalty for using 32-bit variables for indexes?
- It is better to use 64 bits integers to store data in classes or structs? (that we won't want to save to disk or something like this)
- It is better to use 64 bits for a bool type?
- What about conversions between 64 bits integers and floats? Will be better to use doubles now?
  Until now doubles are slower than floats.
- Is there some penalty every time we access a 32-bit variable?

Regards!

Comment: Use whatever expresses your intentions most clearly and only worry about performance penalties, real or imaginary, in the < 0.1% of cases where it actually matters. In situations where it matters consider using the `*_fast_*` types from `<stdint.h>`.

Comment: @PaulR: In this particular case I would kind of disagree. The *size* penalty can be quite significant.

Comment: Only use 64 bits when working with memory or files. Otherwise it's going to be a size bottleneck. BUT... it's always faster to use as many bits that a processor register supports - a trick in which well aligned memory gets handled really fast by the CPU. Using 64 bit values to store an array of numbers 0 to 5 is not the best use, for example.

Comment: The only benefits of compiling for 64-bits are that you can access more than 4GB of memory and that amd64 has more registers than ix86. Most programs don't need the former and the later is easily outweighed by the more cache misses caused by the larger memory consumption. I don't have rigorous measurements for it though.

Comment: @Jan: you're getting mixed up between the two different meaning of "64 bit" - the question is about the use of 64 bit registers, which is independent of whether the address space is 64 bit or not. (The two are easily confused in the case of x86 and x86-64 though, I admit.)

Comment: My advice would be to use the types advertised by the libraries you're dealing with. When the library gives you `std::vector<T>::size_type`, use that; it's the only reliable option. And use the `auto` keyword, of course.

Comment: @PaulR: When the address space is not 64-bit, there are _no_ 64-bit registers either. So the question only applies to cases when there is 64-bit address space. And I am saying that the case is not very important.

Comment: @Jan: that's only true for x86/x86-64 - other architectures are not so restricted - note that the the original question does not specify a particular architecture.

Comment: And even on AMD64/EM64T, while the address space is actually 64 bits, some compilers support an option for 32-bit pointers (which allows more data to fit into cache).

Comment: @PaulR: I totally disagree. For my projects the speed is very important.

Comment: @JanHudec: There are many benefits: More registers, instruction set, ... Its not that simple

Comment: @Darky: the point is that you don't need to optimise 100% of your code base - even for the most performance-critical applications only a small fraction of the code is in the "hot" part of the execution profile. Focus on writing clear, robust code and then optimise only what's needed, *after* you've tested it, timed it and profiled it.

Comment: "*Premature optimization is the root of all evil*" (c) Donald Knuth

Answer (score 4):

I agree with @MarkB but want to provide more detail on some topics.

On x64, there are more registers available (twice as many).  The standard calling conventions have therefore been designed to take more parameters in registers by default.  So as long as the number of parameters is not excessive (typically 4 or fewer), their types will make no difference.  *They will be promoted to 64 bit and passed in registers anyway.*

Space will be allocated on the stack for those 64 bit registers even though they are passed in registers.  This is by design to make their storage locations simple and contiguous with the those of surplus parameters.  The surplus parameters will be placed on the stack regardless, so size may matter in those cases.

This issue is particularly important for memory data structures.  Using 64 bit where 32 bit is sufficient will waste memory, and more importantly, occupy space in cache lines.  The cache impact is not simple though.  *If your data access pattern is sequential*, that's when you will pay for it by essentially making half of your cache unusable.  (Assuming you only needed half of each 64 bit quantity.)

*If your access pattern is random*, there is no impact on cache performance.  This is because every access occupies a full cache line anyway.

There can be a small impact in accessing integers that are smaller than word size.  However, pipelining and multiple issue of instructions will make it so that the extra instruction (zero or sign extend) will almost always become completely hidden and go unobserved.

The upshot of all this is simple: *choose the integer size that matters for your problem.*  For parameters, the compiler can promote them as needed.  For memory structure, smaller is typically better.

Comment: Note that using 8 or 16 bits integers are more inefficient than using 32-bit integers in x86 platforms. Furthermore, promote an integer is less efficient than do not promote ;)

Comment: @Darky That is true for older implementations (P4), but may be less applicable to current CPUs (anything after P4, except possible the Atom). Have a look at the latency and throughput figures for `mov`, `movzx`, and `movsx` in http://gmplib.org/~tege/x86-timing.pdf, produced by the GMP guys.

Answer (score 3):

You have managed to cram a *ton* of questions into one question here. It looks to me like all your questions basically concern micro-optimizations. As such I'm going to make a two-part answer:

- Don't worry about size from a performance perspective but instead use types that are indicative of the data that they will contain *and trust the compiler's optimizer to sort it out*.
- If performance becomes a concern at some point during development, profile your code. Then you can make algorithmic adjustments as appropriate and *if* the profiler shows that integer operations are causing a problem you can compare different sizes side-by-side for comparison purposes.

Comment: SIMD (MMX, SSE) and cache effects may make 32-bit `float` faster even with truncation.  Furthermore, on x86 machines, `double` is truncated also.

Comment: @Ben Voigt `double` is admittedly also truncated if you use extended precision math to compute your results, but this isn't always the case.

Comment: x87 registers are wider than `double` variables.  I guess you can say that the truncation is trivial if extended precision is disabled, but you're still losing bits of representation.

Comment: @MarkB I managed to double the efficiency of a program by not relying on the kindness of the compiler (a raytracer for example)

Comment: @MarkB: Doubles are slower than floats. You can check it for yourself if you do not believe me.

Comment: I've removed the floating point portion of my answer as I don't have hard evidence to support a particular position.

Answer (score 0):

Use `int` and trust the platform and compiler authors that they have done their job and chose the most efficient representation for it. On most 64-bit platforms it is 32-bits which means that it's no less efficient than 64-bit types.